# Javascript Jquery setTimeout. Need the popup to fade out after some timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am displaying the pop up using the code below:

```
function validatePlaces()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //open popup
        $("#pop").ready(function(){
            $("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
            positionPopup();
        });

        //close popup
        $("#close").click(function(){
            $("#overlay_form").fadeOut(4500);
        });
    });

    //position the popup at the center of the page
    function positionPopup()
    {
        if(!$("#overlay_form").is(':visible'))
        {
            return;
        }
        $("#overlay_form").css({
            left: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 2,
            top: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 7,
            position:'absolute'
        });
    }
    //maintain the popup at center of the page when browser resized
    $(window).bind('resize',positionPopup);


    var placeValue = document.getElementById("form1:placeId").value;
    var countryValue = document.getElementById("form1:countryId").value;
    var continentValue = document.getElementById("form1:continentId").value;

    if(placeValue=="Name Of Places?"||placeValue==" ")
    {
        //alert("Please enter your search place name... ");
        pop(); 
        return false;
    }


    return true;
}
```

**Problem:** Page is refreshing automatically and the pop up vanishes very soon so I need to put a setTimeout. Or if any other solution please provide. Please Help...

Page is refreshing automatically..I have no idea why..

Pop Form Code Used:

```
<form id="overlay_form" style="display:none; opacity:0.8; background-color: gray; border-
    radius:10px; height:65px; margin-top: 12%; width:350px;"> 
    <img border="0" src="../../resources/images/error.png" alt="" width="30" height="22"/> 
    <p style="font-family:times new roman ; font-size:18px; color: white;"> 
       Enter your search place name...</p> 
    <a href="#" id="close" style="color: black;"><b>Close</b></a> 
</form>
```

Comment: Didn't see any `setTimeout` in the code. Did you even try using it?

Comment: I'm afraid you've to rethink this. You can't keep a pop-up visible after refresh, if it's not visible at page start.

Comment: I need to use timeout the that the pop up waits on the page for sometime and then the page reloads. I need to include the settimeout within the code.

Comment: Then you need also to show the code which reloads your page, so we can see how you've arranged automatic refresh.

Comment: Page is refreshing automatically..I have no idea why.. Below is the code used for the pop up form: <form id="overlay_form" style="display:none; opacity:0.8; background-color: gray; border-radius:10px; height:65px; margin-top: 12%; width:350px;">
   <img border="0" src="../../resources/images/error.png" alt="" width="30" height="22"/>
   <p style="font-family:times new roman ; font-size:18px; color: white;"> Enter your search place name...</p>
   <a href="#" id="close" style="color: black;"><b>Close</b></a>
   </form>

Comment: You need to indent you code. Left-aligned code is unreadable.

Comment: @Tomalak Code formatted, you're welcome ;)

Comment: @Turnerj I could have done it myself. I had a reason to ask the OP to do it.

Comment: @Tomalak True, it would be better for future questions if the person asking the question formatted it. My comment was both a slight jab at formatting it yourself (no offence) and also to let you know that now it being formatted, you can help out with answering the question if you so desire (as you don't get notifications for question edits on a question you comment on). Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @user2446821 You need to have control over the automatic refreshing, there's nothing you can do outside that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem when using List.js whereby immediately after clicking on sort, the page would refresh. Hours later I tried changing my form element to div and this fixed it. I think it was behaving as if its been submitted or something. I know its late but any other person please try changing form to div. and it will stop the page refreshing.

Answer (score -1):

```
//5000 is the time in mili seconds after which you want to hide the popup
$("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
```

Comment: How does this do the job, when the page is refreshed during the delay?